# Is port map (A => (others => x)) legal in VHDL 2008?

Tags: vhdl

I have an entity `dummy` with an input port signal of type `std_logic_vector`:

```vhdl
entity dummy is
    generic (
        LENGTH : natural);
    port (
        A : in std_logic_vector (LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
        Q : out std_logic);
end entity;
```

When instantiating `dummy`, is it allowed to associate `A` with `(others => x)`, where `x` is a signal of type `std_logic`?

```vhdl
dummy_i: entity work.dummy
    generic map (
        LENGTH => 4)
    port map (
        A => (others => x),
        Q => open);
```

ModelSim 10.7b stops with the error message

> ** Fatal: (vsim-3420) Array lengths do not match. Left is 4 (3 downto 0). Right is 0 (-1 downto 0 (null array))

It works, however, if

- I use `(others => '0')` instead of `(others => x)` (replace #1a with #1b), or
- the length of port signal `A` of entity `dummy` does not depend on the generic (replace #2a with #2b).

Full MWE:

````vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dummy is
    generic (
        LENGTH : natural);
    port (
        A : in std_logic_vector (LENGTH - 1 downto 0); -- #2a
        --A : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); -- #2b
        Q : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture rtl of dummy is
begin
    Q <= '0';
end architecture;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity modelsim_others_bug_testbench is
end modelsim_others_bug_testbench;

architecture rtl of modelsim_others_bug_testbench is 
    signal x : std_logic;
begin
    x <= '0';

    dummy_i: entity work.dummy
        generic map (
            LENGTH => 4)
        port map (
            A => (others => x), -- #1a
            --A => (others => '0'), -- #1b
            Q => open);
end architecture;
```
````

Comment: Heh, that's interesting, I can get it working by defining a new type that's an array of `std_logic`

Comment: What you have done is not legal. What exactly do you want to achieve? Remember that VHDL is strongly typed and std_logic is different type than std_logic_vector even if  the length of the vector is  1 (0 downto 0).

Comment: @AlBundy note that I'm not assigning `x` but `(others => x)`. I want all elements of that vector to be `x`.

Comment: I've edited the question to `LENGTH => 4` instead of `LENGTH => 1` to emphasize that `A` is indeed intended as a vector.

Comment: I bet this is going to end up being a problem with when genetics are evaluated. Try to assign a std_logic_vector outside the port map using (others => x). Then you can assign said vector to A in the port map.

Comment: [IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tI0o.jpg) The anonymous signal assignment to an aggregate containing `others` is legal (
9.3.3.3 Array aggregates para 7 "e) As a value expression in an assignment statement, where the target is a declared object (or member thereof), and either the subtype of the target is a fully constrained array subtype or the target is a slice name").  That looks like a Modelsim issue.Your error message appears to be for LENGTH = 1. You can use an intermediary signal as an actual with the subtype of  A.

Comment: Question updated to include the MWE instead of linking to pastebin. Code and error message updated to reflect the recent change to `LENGTH => 4`.

Comment: Assigning to an intermediary signal (as suggested by user110971 and user8352) ist what I ended up doing, but it makes the code harder to read and maintain, especially if it has to be done for a high number of signals.

Comment: Prior to -2008 an expression as an actual had to be static, and (others => x) isn't. Modelsim appears to be incapable of correctly retrieving the subtype of the anonymous signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prior to VHDL-2008:**
You cannot perform such action : `A => (others => x)` because this line is seen as an operation and that is not possible in an instantiation.

(like in this post for example: [Warning : Actual for formal port a is neither a static name nor a globally static expression](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/184893/warning-actual-for-formal-port-a-is-neither-a-static-name-nor-a-globally-stati))

However, there is a way to work around that, you have to create a new signal `y` :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dummy is
    generic (
        LENGTH : natural);
    port (
        --A : in std_logic_vector (LENGTH - 1 downto 0); -- #2a
        A : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0); -- #2b
        Q : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture rtl of dummy is
begin
    Q <= '0';
end architecture;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity modelsim_others_bug_testbench is
end modelsim_others_bug_testbench;

architecture rtl of modelsim_others_bug_testbench is 
    signal   x  : std_logic;
    signal   y  : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); --New signals
begin

    x <= '1';
    y <= (others => x);

    dummy_i: entity work.dummy(rtl)
        generic map (
            LENGTH => 4)
        port map (
            --A => (others => x),   -- #1a Does not work
            --A => (others => '0'), -- #1b Works
            A => y,                 -- #1c Works
            Q => open);

end architecture;
```

Notice that when copy/pasting your code on Vivado, the error is: `Actual for formal port a is neither a static name nor a globally static expression`

I let you modify your code so that you can use the generic `LENGTH`.

**With VHDL-2008:**

If look in the norm: http://www.fis.agh.edu.pl/~skoczen/hdl/ieee_std/ieee1076-2008.pdf
You can find on paragraph 6.5.6.3 Port clauses:

> If a formal port of mode in is associated with an expression that is not globally static (see 9.4.1) and the
>   formal is of an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type requiring determination of index
>   ranges from the actual according to the rules of 5.3.2.2, then the expression shall be one of the following:
>
> - The name of an object whose subtype is globally static
> - An indexed name whose prefix is one of the members of this list
> - A slice name whose prefix is one of the members of this list and whose discrete range is a globally static discrete range
> - An aggregate, provided all choices are locally static and all expressions in element associations are expressions described in this list
> - A function call whose return type mark denotes a globally static subtype
> - A qualified expression or type conversion whose type mark denotes a globally static subtype
> - An expression described in this list and enclosed in parentheses

In other word, in VHDL-2008, the code you provided works (I have no error using it with Vivado 2018.1, simulation works as expected)